angular v18 leaflet integration not working
I'm trying to set up a new angular v18 app with a leaflet map integration but while I'm configuring leaflet settings almost exactly to how I set them up in a working angular 17 app, the map just doesn't want to display correctly. It is a very minimal setup for the time being but the difficulties in getting the map to display have been somewhat of a bottleneck... Could anyone help?
app config ts:
import {
  ApplicationConfig,
  provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection,
} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
  ],
};

map component ts:
import {
  Component,
  inject,
  AfterViewInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from '../map.service';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../wcm-modules/material/material.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-layer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MaterialModule],
  template: ` <div id="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>`,
  styles: `
  .map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;}
  `,
})
export class MapLayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private mapService: MapService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('MapLayerComponent initialized!');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('Attempting to create map!');
    this.mapService.createMap('map');
  }
}

map service ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MapService {
  public map!: L.Map;

  // Function to create a map
  public createMap(mapId: string): any {
    console.log('Map Sercive create map function started!');
    this.map = L.map(mapId).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors',
    }).addTo(this.map);
  }
}


What errors do you have in the console ?

None, really - thats kinda my issue. The console logs are all displayed in the correct order and no irregular network processes but also not the amount of successful queries to the map provider - only a few map tiles come back but aren't displayed at all or sometimes in a chaotic fashion.

I couldn't reproduce your exact example (as I don't have MaterialModule) but I think the problem is your CSS selector in map.component.ts.
map-container is not a class but an ID, use:
#map-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

